# Getting errors from ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, warning-messages

I am a newcomer to Mathematica (use ver 9.0).

I just want to fit the experimental data to a system of odes' by using NonlinearModelFit. The data, contains time in the first column and product concentration in the second. The model contains 4 species, species p1[t] is the one I want to fit the data to.

```
data = {{18.283, 0.0003365}, {39.415, 0.0003892}, {60.547, 
    0.00045}, {81.679, 0.0005631}, {102.811, 0.0006446}, {123.943, 
    0.0006756}, {145.075, 0.0007655}, {166.207, 0.0008306}, {187.339, 
    0.0008814}, {208.471, 0.000896}, {229.603, 0.0009816}, {250.735, 
    0.0011191}, {271.867, 0.0010797}, {292.999, 0.0011473}, {314.131, 
    0.0012265}, {335.263, 0.0013187}, {356.395, 0.0012809}, {377.527, 
    0.0013523}, {398.659, 0.0013841}, {419.791, 0.0014507}, {440.923, 
    0.0014885}, {462.055, 0.0014898}, {483.187, 0.0015491}, {504.319, 
    0.0015838}, {525.451, 0.0015651}, {546.583, 0.0015903}, {567.715, 
    0.0016328}, {588.847, 0.0016423}, {609.979, 0.0016149}, {631.111, 
    0.0016508}, {652.243, 0.0016296}, {673.375, 0.0016465}, {694.507, 
    0.0016776}, {715.639, 0.0016668}, {736.771, 0.0016685}, {757.903, 
    0.0016967}, {779.035, 0.001717}, {800.167, 0.0016997}, {821.299, 
    0.001721}};
tmax = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
e0 == 0.0002;
k21 == 0.001;
kh == 0.0001;
model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{s'[
      t] == -16  s[t] (0.0002 - x1[t] - x2[t]) + k21 x1[t] - kh  s[t],
    x1'[t] == 16  s[t] (0.0002 - x1[t] - x2[t]) - (k21 + k2) x1[t],
    x2'[t] == k2 x1[t] - k3 x2[t],
    p1'[t] == k2 x1[t] + kh s[t],
    s[0] == 0.002, x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, p1[0] == 0}, 
   p1, {t, 0, tmax}, {k2, k3}];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  model[k2, k3][t], {{k2, 0.4}, {k3, 0.7}}, {t, 0, tmax}]
plotfit = Plot[fit[t], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.0021}];
plotdata = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]];
Show[plotfit, plotdata]
```

When I run the code, it produces a lot of messages:

> NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument
>   General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable.
>   ParametricNDSolve::dsvar: 0.016777965285714284` cannot be used as a variable.
>   General::ivar: 0.016777965285714284` is not a valid variable.

Would anyone please help me to fix it.

Comment: You probably used `=` instead of `==` earlier.  That leaves a definition lingering.  Just quit the kernel (to purge the old definitions) and try again.

Comment: The last argument in `fit=NonlinearModelFit[...]` should be `t` instead of  ` {t, 0, tmax}`.

Comment: I fixed all the above, but errors still appear: ParametricNDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t$317 == 0.`. >> General::stop: Further output of ParametricNDSolveValue::ndnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value {<<1>>} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {39} at {k2,k3} = {0.4,0.7}. >>

Comment: By fixing all of the above, do you mean that you replaced `e0 == 0.0002; k21 == 0.001; kh == 0.0001;` with `e0 = 0.0002; k21 = 0.001; kh = 0.0001;`?  Secondly, your data looks like it intersects the y-axis at ~0.00025, but your initial condition is `p1[0]==0`.  That could make it a difficult to fit if the model is constrained to go through 0.

Answer (score 2):

The following fixes your Equal versus Set error and sets up a Manipulate to help set initial guesses for parameters.

```
data = {{18.283, 0.0003365}, {39.415, 0.0003892}, {60.547, 
    0.00045}, {81.679, 0.0005631}, {102.811, 0.0006446}, {123.943, 
    0.0006756}, {145.075, 0.0007655}, {166.207, 0.0008306}, {187.339, 
    0.0008814}, {208.471, 0.000896}, {229.603, 0.0009816}, {250.735, 
    0.0011191}, {271.867, 0.0010797}, {292.999, 0.0011473}, {314.131, 
    0.0012265}, {335.263, 0.0013187}, {356.395, 0.0012809}, {377.527, 
    0.0013523}, {398.659, 0.0013841}, {419.791, 0.0014507}, {440.923, 
    0.0014885}, {462.055, 0.0014898}, {483.187, 0.0015491}, {504.319, 
    0.0015838}, {525.451, 0.0015651}, {546.583, 0.0015903}, {567.715, 
    0.0016328}, {588.847, 0.0016423}, {609.979, 0.0016149}, {631.111, 
    0.0016508}, {652.243, 0.0016296}, {673.375, 0.0016465}, {694.507, 
    0.0016776}, {715.639, 0.0016668}, {736.771, 0.0016685}, {757.903, 
    0.0016967}, {779.035, 0.001717}, {800.167, 0.0016997}, {821.299, 
    0.001721}};
lp = ListPlot[data, PlotLegends -> {"data-p1"}];
(* Define constants *)
tmax = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
e0 = 0.0002;
k21 = 0.001;
kh = 0.0001;
(* System of ODEs *)
system = {Derivative[1][p1][t] == 0.0001` s[t] + k2 x1[t], 
   Derivative[1][s][t] == -0.0001` s[t] + 0.001` x1[t] - 
     16 s[t] (0.0002` - x1[t] - x2[t]), 
   Derivative[1][x1][t] == -(0.001` + k2) x1[t] + 
     16 s[t] (0.0002` - x1[t] - x2[t]), 
   Derivative[1][x2][t] == k2 x1[t] - k3 x2[t], p1[0] == 0, 
   s[0] == 0.002`, x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0};
vbles = {p1, s, x1, x2};
(* Note position of p1 *)
modelpos = 1;
parms = {k2, k3};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, vbles, {t, 0, tmax}, parms];
model[p__Real][t_] := #[[modelpos]] &@Through[pfun[p][t], List]
(* Build Manipulate sliders *)
Manipulate[global = {k2, k3};
  Show[
  lp,
  Plot[Evaluate[model[k2, k3][t]], {t, 0, tmax}, 
       PlotRange -> {0., 0.8}, PlotLegends -> {"fitted-p1"}],
   ImageSize -> Large], 
  {{k2, 0.4}, 0.004, 40., Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k3, 0.7}, 
  0.007, 70., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
Dynamic@global
(* {32.15, 0.007} *)
```

[image: Manipulate Image]

Now, we will use FindFit to estimate the parameters using the initial guess defined by Dynamic above.

```
(* Initial Guess Based on Slider Values *)
initguess = MapThread[List, {parms, First@Dynamic@global}]
fit = Quiet@
  FindFit[data, model[k2, k3][t], initguess, t, 
   Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}}]
Show[lp, Plot[Evaluate[model[k2, k3][t] /. fit], {t, 0, tmax}, 
      PlotRange -> {0., 0.8}, PlotLegends -> {"fitted-p1"}],
  ImageSize -> Large]
(* {{k2, 32.15}, {k3, 0.007}} *)
(* {k2 -> 2.68866, k3 -> 0.209279} *)
```

[image: Real data fit]

The fit is okay, but the model has an initial condition of $p1(t=0)==0$ whereas the data does not appear to intersect $(0,0)$. You may want to reconsider your model.  To illustrate the point, we can generate data with test parameters $\{0.4,0.7\}$ as given in the OP and use the same bad initial guess from the slider to show that FindFit can indeed recover the test parameters.

```
(* Test values for parameters *)
testvals = {0.4, 0.7}
initguess
{sol, samples} = First@NDSolve[
     (system /. Thread[parms -> testvals])~
      Join~{WhenEvent[Mod[t, tmax/50] == 0, 
        Sow[{t, p1[t], s[t], x1[t], x2[t]}]]},
     vbles, {t, 0., tmax}, MaxStepSize -> 1] // Reap;
samples = First@samples;
simdata = samples[[All, {1, modelpos + 1}]];
simlp = ListPlot[simdata, PlotLegends -> {"Sim Data - p1"}];
fit = Quiet@
  FindFit[samples[[All, {1, 2}]], model[k2, k3][t], initguess, t, 
   Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}}]
Show[simlp, Plot[Evaluate[model[k2, k3][t] /. fit], {t, 0, tmax}, 
      PlotRange -> {0., 0.8}, PlotLegends -> {"fitted-p1"}],
  ImageSize -> Large]
(* {0.4, 0.7} *)
(* {{k2, 32.15}, {k3, 0.007}} *)
(* {k2 -> 0.398766, k3 -> 0.702116} *)
```

[image: Fit on simulated data]